# Eventos de react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, eventos, react-hooks

Soy desarrollador Junior que esta desarrollando formularios en React. En uno de esos formularios debo hacer un evento que al darle click a un icon cambie a otro evento. Por ejemplo:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Que cuando le des click al icono del lápiz cambie a otro componente en la misma pantalla. Por ejemplo:[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Yo investigue sobre los hooks, eventos y states y se que la solución va por ahí, pero los casos no se aplica a este especifico. Entonces me gustaría que alguien me explicara y me diera unos ejemplos de como podría res ver esto, así comí de darme alguien a documentación.

Gracias y que tenga buen día!

Comment: https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: yo lo haría de la siguiente forma, es tarjeta es un componete, donde con el useState(false) muestra 2 html, si es true, muestra lo que hay en la primera foto, si es false, muestra el formulario, el tema que estas buscando especificamente se llama renderizado condicional https://es.reactjs.org/docs/conditional-rendering.html

Comment: Primero que nada bienvenido a Stackoverflow en Español. Te recomiendo que hagas el [tour] y leas [ask] y [example]. Por otro lado, te paso la documentación oficial de ReactJs para que la leas (https://es.reactjs.org/). Mi recomendación es que antes de preguntar leas la docu y trates de entenderla e intentes llegar a una solución por tu cuenta. Como está redactada tu pregunta no queda claro cuál es el error que estás obteniendo ya que no agregaste el código de lo que has intentado. Saludos